# Protocol oriented Programming Swift - Identifiable

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols, identifiable

Lets say I want to model a fantasy-game with protocol oriented programming in swift.
the code below produces the following error:

> Protocol 'Character' can only be used as a generic constraint because
> it has Self or associated type requirements

what's the problem here? how to do it right?

```swift
protocol Character: Identifiable {
    var name: String {get}
    var maxHealt: Int {get}
    var healt: Int { get set }
}
extension Character {
    var id: String {return name}
    mutating func setHealth(newValue: Int) {
        healt = newValue
    }
}

protocol Fighter {
    var attackPower: Int { get }
}
extension Fighter {
    func attack(enemy: Character ) -> Character {
        var enemy = enemy
        enemy.setHealth(newValue: enemy.maxHealt - self.attackPower)
        return enemy
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add generic constraints.

```
extension Fighter {
    func attack<T: Character>(enemy: T ) -> T { //<-- Here
        var enemy = enemy
        enemy.setHealth(newValue: enemy.maxHealt - self.attackPower)
        return enemy
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This works! but I don’t understand why the original code is not..